# How to prove $\{ x: | x | < 1\}\subset\mathbb R$ is open?

Tags: general-topology

Show that the set of $\mathbb{R}$  given by $s=\{ x: | x | < 1\}$ is open.

I know it is open but i can't prove it,
I also a complete prove not just a hint and please explain every step.

Comment: What's your definition of the topology?

Comment: What's wrong with hints?

Comment: What is going on with all these downvotes? Clearly the OP is simply not very good at topology and doesn't see how to make the first step. A person is entitled to request complete solutions rather than hints if they don't think hints are going to help them.

Comment: i asked this because i know the definition but i don't know how to apply them so i want a clear proof to understand it fully

Comment: the def i'm using is A is open if for every point in A there exist an open ball (neighborhood) which entirely lies in A >>> so we need to take an arbitrary point in A and choose r the radius of the open ball such that the open ball lies entirely in A

Comment: I do assume all those downvoters think that it is obvious that something which is called an open ball is open and do not realize that this is just a name, and that the claim in fact needs justification (how easy this may be, for a beginner it _is_ confusing). I faced many similar misunderstandings when I had to teach basic topological facts to first year students. This kind of confusion is something which is normal and, for me, easily excusable.

Comment: @Thomas you totally right that is my case thanks for the support

Comment: @amWhy Why not assume good faith and suspect that the OP is like the huge majority of students that know the ideas, even understand how to argue the proof, but hasn't been trained in the art of displaying a formal rigorous proof (art which is can't be developed without seeing others write proofs)?

Comment: @user144349 If you knew me, you'd know that  historically, I've been one of the biggest advocates of students and newish users on this site.

Comment: @amWhy I am currently looking at all (120+ out of 9000+ so far) closed questions (on hold) with the intention of surveying the factual effects of closing questions for not showing work. I can say that your name (among many others of course) is recurrent in the list of closers. I can also say that most of the questions closed for this reason didn't really deserve to be closed. Why, if you are historically known for advocate for students, change that? I think this treatment of certain questions is not producing any good effect. All questions get their answers anyway. And good questions are ...

Comment: ... getting punished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ x\in S$. Then $x>-1 $ and $x<1$. Let $\epsilon _1=|x-(-1)|$ and $\epsilon_2=|x-1|$. Let $\epsilon=\frac {1}{2} min(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2)$. Then $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\subset S$.

Comment: thanks a lot it was helpful